# Недопустимое имя объекта в запросе BULK INSERT в таблицу из CSV файла

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводит ошибку, хотя база и таблица создана, что можно сделать?

Comment: `ZKZS.dbo.QuestionforDiscussion`

Comment: Сообщение 7301, уровень 16, состояние 2, строка 5
Не удалось получить требуемый интерфейс ("IID_IColumnsInfo") от поставщика OLE DB "BULK" для связанного сервера "(null)". (Не получилось пишет вот это)

Comment: Вы можете попробовать добавить еще один параметр в BULK LOAD: `CODEPAGE = '65001',` Кроме того, отредактируйте исходный вопрос и добавьте образец файла * .csv